# Can we construct anti-commutative functions?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

If $f(g(x))=-g(f(x))=h(x)$, then we say $f$ and $g$ anti commutative. 
Suppose the domain of both functions are integers, rational numbers, and real numbers separately.
Also, assume $f$ and $g$ are bijections.
Can we find $f$ and $g$ given $h$?

For example if $h(x)=x$ ,then such $f, g$ does not exist. Is there any theory related to this question?

Comment: Do you mean (anti-) commutative?

Comment: @Bacon yes I will fix that

Comment: There is no need to consider the cases of integers and rational numbers separately, since there is a bijection $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$ that preserves negation.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to answer once you put it into the language of group theory.  Let $D$ be our domain, and let $n:D\to D$ be the map $n(x)=-x$.  Let $G$ be the group of all permutations of $D$.  You are then asking for which $h\in G$ there exist $f,g\in G$ such that $h=fg=ngf$.  Since $g$ must be $f^{-1}h$ for this to be true, this is equivalent to asking for which $h\in G$ there exists $f\in G$ such that $h=nf^{-1}hf$, or equivalently $$n^{-1}h=f^{-1}hf.$$

That is, you are just asking when $h$ and $n^{-1}h$ are conjugate.  Two elements of $G$ are conjugate iff they have the same cycle structure: that is, for each $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$, they have the same number of orbits with $k$ elements.

In this case, $n^{-1}h$ is just the function $x\mapsto -h(x)$.  So such $f$ and $g$ exist iff $h$ and $x\mapsto -h(x)$ have the same cycle structure (and in that case you take $f$ to be any bijection that matches up their cycle structures).